# Listar archivos en linux que empiecen por una letra concreta

Tags: linux, lista, ordenamiento, putty

mi duda es la siguiente: en un directorio he creado varios archivos de texto, ¿hay alguna manera de que se listen solo los que empiece por X letra?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Algo así: `ls X*`?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que haz intentado?

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio! Es como dices.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el comando `ls`:

```
> ls
# archivo1    archivo2    archivo3    file1    file2    file3

> ls -d a*
# archivo1    archivo2    archivo3
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta llamada del comando ls.

```
ls -d [letra*]*
```

Ejemplo: ls -d[a*]*

Te mostrará todos los archivos y directorios que empiecen por "a"